# Build fails when pushing to Heroku due to unexpected token in no-longer-existing file

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, babel-loader

I am making a webapp using a boilerplate i found online.  I decided to use CanvasJS to display a graph, and it worked lovely after dropping the dependancies into an assets folder within my project.  When I couldn't push to Heroku due to a failing build revolving around CanvasJS, I decided to switch to Recharts and delete all references to CanvasJS.  When I push to Heroku now, I get the same error as before (seen below):

```
remote:        > react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_8454890d5cf17da8345e5f577f4f5487
remote:        > cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config config/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-b
ailout
remote:
remote:        Hash: 90d3a9367d4988ba0f97
remote:        Version: webpack 4.34.0
remote:        Time: 18718ms
remote:        Built at: 07/30/2019 2:48:43 AM
remote:         5 assets
remote:        Entrypoint main = main.161cd093393cb111dcb1.js
remote:
remote:        ERROR in ./assets/canvasjs/canvasjs.react.js 6:24
remote:        Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:24)
remote:        File was processed with these loaders:
remote:         * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
remote:        You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
remote:        |
remote:        | class CanvasJSChart extends React.Component {
remote:        >        static _cjsContainerId = 0
remote:        |        constructor(props) {
remote:        |                super(props);
remote:         @ ./app/containers/HomePage/PieChart.js 24:0-68 25:20-33
remote:         @ ./app/containers/HomePage/HomePage.js
remote:         @ ./app/containers/HomePage/index.js
remote:         @ ./app/containers/HomePage/Loadable.js
remote:         @ ./app/containers/App/App.js
remote:         @ ./app/containers/App/index.js
remote:         @ ./app/app.js
remote:         @ multi ./app/app.js
remote:        Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
remote:             1 asset
remote:            Entrypoint undefined = index.html
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 2
remote: npm ERR! react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config config/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress -
-hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 2
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the react-redux-boilerplate@1.0.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I completely deleted the canvasjs folder from within the assets folder, did **npm uninstall canvasjs** in case I installed it through npm, deleted PieChart.js from my HomePage folder, deleted the reference to it in the HomePage.js file, but I still get the same error.  It's saying there's an unexpected token in a file that doesn't even exist anymore.

I've tried **npm run build** to get a clean build, but it did nothing.  Why is it detecting a folder that doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you sure you committed the changes and pushed the correct branch to Heroku?